# Bootstrap search box coordinates in navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar, search-box

How can I assign coordinates to search box in navbar. I need a result like on the picture.

Picture: 
[image]

### [Bootply Link](http://www.bootply.com/z5BLGz3sLv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you exactly mean by giving coordinates? If you want to move the search input inside the navbar you can easily change the style of the input element to -

```
position: fixed;
right: 18%; // depends on your requirement 
top: 3%; // depends on your requirement
```

This code can be written along with `style="width: 310px;"` or by giving id to the div and writing in the stylesheet separately.

```
#your_id {
    position: fixed;
    right: 18%; // depends on your requirement 
    top: 3%; // depends on your requirement  
}
```

and give the div/input tag this id

```
<input id="your_id" class="form-control " placeholder="Поиск" style="position: fixed; right: 18%; top: 3%; width:310px" type="text">
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the grid system along with the bootstrap navbar.

[Bootstrap Navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)